# Titanium Appcelerator: How do I target $(this) element?

Tags: ios, animation, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, transition

I am designing a flashcard app using titanium appcelerator, the final aim is to use a scrollable view to display each card in the 'pack' and then on tapping a single card (i.e. the card in view) this should rotate about it's axis (i.e. flip over) to reveal the reverse.

You can see from the diagram below what I am hoping to achieve.

[image]

Unfortunately when tap one of the panels, instead of it's child view animating, instead the **last child** in the scrollableview animates.

I understand this is something to do with the fact that I am assigning variables in a loop but if someone can look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong that would be great.

In JQuery it would look something like this

```
$(FrontView).click(function(){

$(this).parent().flip() //how do I access $(this) and $(this).parent() in Appcelerator?

});
```

Here is my appcelerator code:

```
while(rows.isValidRow()){

         var FrontView = Ti.UI.createView({

          backgroundImage: '/global/card_bg.png',
          width: 295,
         height:297

    });  

         var BackView = Ti.UI.createView({

          backgroundImage: '/global/card_bg.png',
          width: 295,
          height:297

    });  


 var ControlView = Titanium.UI.createView({
 backgroundColor:"#333",
 bubbleParent : false,
 width: 295,
 height:297,
 top : 100

}); 

FrontView.addEventListener('singletap', function() {
        Ti.API.info('singletap');
        ControlView.animate({view:BackView,transition:Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_RIGHT});

    });

BackView.addEventListener('singletap', function() {
        Ti.API.info('singletap');
ControlView.animate({view:FrontView,transition:Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_LEFT});

    });


  $.scrollable_view.addView(ControlView);
  ControlView.add(BackView);  
  ControlView.add(FrontView);  

 rows.next();

} //endwhile
```

**Can anybody help?**

Answer (score 1):

If you put a return variable in your event callbacks, you can get access to the source of the tap.  Try this and see if it works:

```
FrontView.addEventListener('singletap', function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('singletap');
    e.source.animate({view:BackView,transition:Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_RIGHT});
});

BackView.addEventListener('singletap', function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('singletap');
    e.source.animate({view:FrontView,transition:Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_LEFT});
});
```

Comment: I don't think this will work since e.source will either be FrontView of BackView (or some child of those), not ControlView.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it works when you flip the card in the EventListener of your Scrollable View.
Check this out: https://gist.github.com/4683264